# I forgot my sudo password and I need to change it with the terminal

Tags: password-recovery

I have got a computer running Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu and I can't change it via grub.

Comment: any other users in the adm group?

Comment: Did you see any error when you change it via grub ?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: no ther are no other users and I just can't go into recovery mode it dosn't let me the computer resets

Answer (score 1):

Well if you really cannot go to the recovery mode, try doing the following:

a) boot using a live CD, mount the root FS in rw-mode

b) create a new password hash:

```
mkpasswd -m sha-512 -s
```

Enter the new password, you will get the hash string for it

c) manually put the hash string into the /etc/shadow file for whichever user you need it for, replacing the original string (to be inserted after the first colon `:`)

d) reboot and use the new password

e) rechange the password using `passwd`

Note that this is a pretty raw approach and you should make sure not to corrupt the shadow file. (Maybe a backup of the file would do good)